# Android Talkback reading "No" as "Number" sometimes

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibility, screen-readers, talkback

Currently have text we set to a field as "yes" or "no". But when it is set to "no", Talkback will read out "Number". If talkback is turned on in the same screen. Then "no" is being read out correctly. Any solutions to this? I did set the content description as "no" and still the same.

Comment: Try adding a period. It's been a while but from what I remember punctuation can make a huge difference.

Comment: I tried period and to lower case, still the same

Comment: Have you tried upper case? Also try different punctuation - if *number* is abbreviated to *no* some style standards would expect a period anyway (e.g. *no. 1*). Talkback can be a bit silly and extremely inconsistent sometimes

Comment: Yes and No are not great responses from a UX perspective or a11y as they are not great words to describe the result of an action or a state. What action are you really asking for in this case? Screenreaders have different punctuation and verbosity settings so try not to fool them: https://www.deque.com/blog/dont-screen-readers-read-whats-screen-part-1-punctuation-typographic-symbols/

Comment: While I agree Yes/No aren't _great_ in most context, that's not true in all cases. Yes and No are very simple words. To the question "are you authorized to do XYZ?" you don't always want to offer: "Yes, I am authorized to do XYZ", You offer Yes/No. We could talk about what is best UX and what not, but the problem here is stated in the OP's question: `If talkback is turned on in the same screen. Then "no" is being read out correctly.` This means there's a non-deterministic behavior depending when was talkback turned on. And that is likely a TB bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend a funky spelling just to get the right pronunciation because that will confuse Braille users.  They'll read "yes" and "noo" with the Braille device.  They'll probably and assume you misspelled "no" so it might not be a big deal, but in general, you don't try to fake out the screen reader.  The user can adjust their screen reader talkback settings to aid in pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is adding quotation marks to the `contentDescription`:

Before:
`No, x`

After:
`"No", x`